# Is there a good video showing how to use SoapUI with SalesForce/ExactTarget APIs?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, fuel-sdk, training

Anyone that has successfully used SoapUI (free version) to make and debug SOAP requests to ExactTarget endpoints? I will gladly buy you lunch if you can show me how this is done.

If I understand the documentation, you need to authenticate first, to get a token, which you then use in the SOAP envelope in subsequent requests.

I cannot find the mechanism for obtaining that initial token, so I have yet to get SoapUI to do anything useful in helping to learn ET's SOAP API.

Is it possible? Do you need to buy the Pro version to get Oauth2?

Comment: Is OAuth a requirement?  Because you don't technically need it to utilize SFMCs SOAP API.

Comment: Okay - well, 95% of development is knowing the right question to ask. I've rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use SOAP UI to get an access token with the free version.

1. In SOAP UI, select File > New REST Project
2. When prompted for path, enter: https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
3. In the window that pops up, change Method to POST from GET.
4. Paste in the following in the bottom left pane for the request payload:

   {
     "clientId": "gyjzvytv7ukqtfn3x2qdyfsn",
     "clientSecret": "************"
   }
5. Substitue in clientID and ClientSecret from your registered app from App Center.
6. Double check the Media-Type is application/json which should be the default.
7. Click the execute button in the upper right.
8. This will provide the token which can be copy/pasted in to other requests for authentication.

Details on this route at:
https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/auth/requestToken.html